# How to draw a sine wave using line renderer from point A to point B

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, trigonometry, spline

Following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAGkn0ETFX4), I'm trying to use Line Renderer component to draw a sine wave from point A to B.I'm using the input mouse position. However what I did so far is not working, it just draw the sine wave along the x axis, I need to draw it from the start point to the input mouse position.

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Vector3 newPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        newPos.z = 0;
        CreatePointMarker(newPos);
        GenerateNewLine();
    }
}

private void CreatePointMarker(Vector3 pointPosition)
{
    Instantiate(linePointPrefab, pointPosition, Quaternion.identity);
} 

private void GenerateNewLine()
{
    GameObject[] allPoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("PointMarker");
    Vector3[] allPointPositions = new Vector3[allPoints.Length];
    var pointList = new List<Vector3>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i ++)
        {
            var dir = allPoints[0].transform.position - allPoints[1].transform.position;
            float x = dir.x * i;
            float y = Mathf.Sin(x * Time.time);
            var sine = new Vector3(x, y, 0f);
            var tangentLine = allPoints[0].transform.position + sine;

            pointList.Add(tangentLine);
        }
        SpawnLineGenerator(pointList.ToArray());
    }
}

private void SpawnLineGenerator(Vector3[] linePoints)
{
    GameObject newLineGen = Instantiate(lineGeneratorPrefab);
    LineRenderer lRend = newLineGen.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

    lRend.positionCount = linePoints.Length;
    lRend.SetPositions(linePoints);
}
```

Comment: Where does the `50` come from? . `Mathf.Sin()` expects the angle in radians, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Strictly speaking its impossible to generate a Sin wave from 2 points as there is not enough information. If you assume your 2 points define a frequency then you have frequency, and y offset and x offset but you are still missing amplitude

Comment: @500-InternalServerError it came from here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAGkn0ETFX4

Comment: You would need to rotate the sinus wave somehow ... I found a promising maths solution [here](http://mathman.biz/html/rotatingsine.html)

Comment: @Washcloth isn't the amplitude sinus -1 to 1 ? I guess what OP means is simply to have a startpoint and an endpoint that can be on a different axis than the X-axis ... if you watched the example video you can see that the frequency increases over time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative I would suggest to instead use

```
lineRenderer.useWorlsSpace = false;
```

so the points are no longer set in worldspace but in the local space relative to the linerenderer transform.

Now you can simply rotate the linerenderer transform to point towards the latest user input position.

*I couldn't use your code example since I don't know what your prefabs are and do so I created my own from the code in the given Video. I hope you can reuse/recreate the parts necessary*

```
public class SinusWave : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 initalPosition;
    public int pointCount = 10;
    public LineRenderer line;

    private Vector3 secondPosition;
    private Vector3[] points;
    private float segmentWidth;

    private void Awake()
    {
        line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();

        line.positionCount = pointCount;

        // tell the linerenderer to use the local 
        // transform space for the point coorindates
        line.useWorldSpace = false;

        points = new Vector3[pointCount];
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            // Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint needs a value in Z
            // for the distance to camera
            secondPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition - Vector3.forward * Camera.main.transform.position.z);
            secondPosition.z = 0;

            var dir = secondPosition - initalPosition;
            // get the segmentWidth from distance to end position
            segmentWidth = Vector3.Distance(initalPosition, secondPosition) / pointCount;

            // get the difference angle in the Z axis between the current transform.right
            // and the direction
            var angleDifference = Vector3.SignedAngle(transform.right, dir, Vector3.forward);
            // and rotate the linerenderer transform by that angle in the Z axis
            // so the result will be that it's transform.right
            // points now towards the clicked position
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * angleDifference, Space.World);
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < points.Length; ++i)
        {
            float x = segmentWidth * i;
            float y = Mathf.Sin(x * Time.time);
            points[i] = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
        }
        line.SetPositions(points);
    }
}
```

[image]

---

Btw I just assume here that `GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("PointMarker");` actually retuns all the so far spawned `linePointPrefab` objects.

It would be better to store them right away when you spawn them like

```
private List<Transform> allPoints = new List<Transform>();

...

allPoints.Add(Instantiate(linePointPrefab, pointPosition, Quaternion.identity).transform);
```

then you can skip the usage of `FindObjectsWithType` completely

---

For adopting this local space position also for the line point prefabs you instantiate simply instantiate them as child of the linerenderer transform or spawn them and the linerenderer under the same parent so the relative positions are the same. In this case you wouldn't rotate the linerenderer but the entire parent object so the spawned linepoints are rotated along with it

Comment: Thank you for the tips and for the answer, it really helped me.