# How to simulate travelling wave on a plane in Unity3D with smooth curves instead of discrete pixels?

Tags: unity-game-engine

## Objective

I want to create a simulation below in Unity3D.

[image]

A game object plane with a material attached will be the board on which the travelling wave will be plotted. A script below (based on the accepted answer of my previous question) is also attached to the game object plane.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Plot : MonoBehaviour
{
    const int width = 200;
    const int height = 100;

    const float xmin = -1.0f;
    const float xmax = 7.0f;
    const float ymin = -5.0f;
    const float ymax = 5.0f;

    const float ratio_x2i = (xmax - xmin) / (width - 1);
    const float ratio_j2y = (height - 1) / (ymax - ymin);

    float GetX(int i) => ratio_x2i * i + xmin;
    int GetJ(float y) => (int)(ratio_j2y * (ymax - y));

    float f(float x) => 4 * Mathf.Sin(2 * x);


    Material mat;
    Texture2D tx;
    float t = 0f;
    const float dt = 0.05f;


    void Start()
    {
        MeshRenderer rend;
        rend = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        UnityEngine.Assertions.Assert.IsNotNull(rend);
        mat = rend.material;
        UnityEngine.Assertions.Assert.IsNotNull(mat);

        //tx = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, true);

    }


    private void Update()
    {
        // recrateing a new Texture2D is very expensive 
        // but I have no idea to erase the previous plot.
        tx = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, true);

        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            float x = GetX(i);
            float y = f(x - t);
            int j = GetJ(y);

            tx.SetPixel(i, j, Color.red);
        }

        tx.Apply(true); 

        mat.mainTexture = tx;
        t -= dt;
    }
}
```

## Question

When the "game" is played, the wave travels to the right but with flickers. It might be because of the expensive recreating a new `Texture2D` in the `Update` game loop. My computer seems to run out of resources in several minutes.

[image]

**So the questions:**

1. What is the correct way to erase the previous plot?
2. Is there any better way, such as drawing line or curve instead of `SetPixel`? I think drawing line much much better because I don't need to care about anti-aliasing and Bresenham line algorithm.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with these waves?  Do you want to store them in memory?

Comment: @0xBFE1A8: I am sorry. I don't understand your question. The travelling wave will run forever as the time goes. Discarding the previous plot is a must to save resources. No need to save them on memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, recreating texture to draw lines is generally a bad idea, I wouldn't recommend to use this method at all.

The fastest way to do this is to use **Vertex/Fragment** shader directly but it requires some shader writing experience.

Alternatively you could use [LineRenderer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.html) component. The line renderer is used to draw free-floating lines in 3D space.

```
void DrawTravellingSineWave(Vector3 startPoint, float amplitude, float wavelength, float waveSpeed){

    float x = 0f;
    float y;
    float k = 2 * Mathf.PI / wavelength;
    float w = k * waveSpeed;
    lineRenderer.positionCount = 200;
    for (int i = 0; i < lineRenderer.positionCount; i++){
        x += i * 0.001f;
        y = amplitude * Mathf.Sin(k * x + w * Time.time);
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(i, new Vector3(x, y, 0) + startPoint);
    }
}
```

[image]

Some useful links:

- [How to draw lines, circles or anything else using Line Renderer](https://www.codinblack.com/how-to-draw-lines-circles-or-anything-else-using-linerenderer/)
- [How to draw a sine wave using line renderer from point A to point B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56583719/how-to-draw-a-sine-wave-using-line-renderer-from-point-a-to-point-b)